# FullCalendar not updating Database using asp.net webforms mssql ajax jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, fullcalendar

I am trying to use a fullcalendar module to see various events. So far only events from the database get populated onto the fullcalendar but any edit or delete or add operation do not get reflected in the database

I have used masterpage and this page is the contentpage
so the master page has style sheets and javascript files such as

```
 <title>ASP.NET FullCalendar</title>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


..

 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/calendarscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my aspx file:EventManagement.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="calendar">
    </div>
    <div id="updatedialog" style="font: 70% 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; margin: 50px;display: none;"
        title="Update or Delete Event">
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="alignRight">
                    Name:</td>
                <td class="alignLeft">
                    <input id="eventName" type="text" size="33" /><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alignRight">
                    Description:</td>
                <td class="alignLeft">
                    <textarea id="eventDesc" cols="30" rows="3" ></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alignRight">
                    Start:</td>
                <td class="alignLeft">
                    <span id="eventStart"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alignRight">
                    End: </td>
                <td class="alignLeft">
                    <span id="eventEnd"></span><input type="hidden" id="eventId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" ></asp:Button>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="delete" ></asp:Button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="addDialog" style="font: 70% 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; margin: 50px;" title="Add Event">
    <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="alignRight">
                    Name:</td>
                <td class="alignLeft">
                    <input id="addEventName" type="text" size="33" /><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alignRight">
                    Description:</td>
                <td class="alignLeft">
                    <textarea id="addEventDesc" cols="30" rows="3" ></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alignRight">
                    Start:</td>
                <td class="alignLeft">
                    <span id="addEventStartDate" ></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alignRight">
                    End:</td>
                <td class="alignLeft">
                    <span id="addEventEndDate" ></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
    </div>
    <div runat="server" id="jsonDiv" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hdClient" runat="server" />
```

my code behind file: EventManagement.aspx.cs

```
public partial class EventManagement : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
        //this method only updates the title and description
        //this is called when an event is clicked on the calendar

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]
        public static string UpdateEvent(CalendarEvent cevent)
        {
            List<int> idList = (List<int>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["idList"];
            if (idList != null && idList.Contains(cevent.id))
            {
                if (CheckAlphaNumeric(cevent.name) && CheckAlphaNumeric(cevent.description))
                {
                    EventDAO.updateEvent(cevent.id, cevent.name, cevent.description);

                    return "updated event with id:" + cevent.id + " update title to: " + cevent.name +
                    " update description to: " + cevent.description;
                }

            }

            return "unable to update event with id:" + cevent.id + " title : " + cevent.name +
                " description : " + cevent.description;
        }

        //this method only updates start and end time
        //this is called when a event is dragged or resized in the calendar
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]
        public static string UpdateEventTime(ImproperCalendarEvent improperEvent)
        {
            List<int> idList = (List<int>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["idList"];
            if (idList != null && idList.Contains(improperEvent.id))
            {
                EventDAO.updateEventTime(improperEvent.id, improperEvent.title, improperEvent.description,
                                         Convert.ToDateTime(improperEvent.start),
                                         Convert.ToDateTime(improperEvent.end),
                                         improperEvent.allDay);  //allDay parameter added for FullCalendar 2.x

                return "updated event with id:" + improperEvent.id + " update start to: " + improperEvent.start +
                    " update end to: " + improperEvent.end;
            }

            return "unable to update event with id: " + improperEvent.id;
        }

        //called when delete button is pressed
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]
        public static String deleteEvent(int id)
        {
            //idList is stored in Session by JsonResponse.ashx for security reasons
            //whenever any event is update or deleted, the event id is checked
            //whether it is present in the idList, if it is not present in the idList
            //then it may be a malicious user trying to delete someone elses events
            //thus this checking prevents misuse
            List<int> idList = (List<int>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["idList"];
            if (idList != null && idList.Contains(id))
            {
                EventDAO.deleteEvent(id);
                return "deleted event with id:" + id;
            }

            return "unable to delete event with id: " + id;
        }

        //called when Add button is clicked
        //this is called when a mouse is clicked on open space of any day or dragged 
        //over mutliple days
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]
        public static int addEvent(ImproperCalendarEvent improperEvent)
        {
            CalendarEvent cevent = new CalendarEvent()
            {
                name = improperEvent.title,
                description = improperEvent.description,
                start = Convert.ToDateTime(improperEvent.start),
                end = Convert.ToDateTime(improperEvent.end),
                allDay = improperEvent.allDay
            };

            if (CheckAlphaNumeric(cevent.name) && CheckAlphaNumeric(cevent.description))
            {
                int key = EventDAO.addEvent(cevent);

                List<int> idList = (List<int>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["idList"];

                if (idList != null)
                {
                    idList.Add(key);
                }

                return key; //return the primary key of the added cevent object
            }

            return -1; //return a negative number just to signify nothing has been added
        }

        private static bool CheckAlphaNumeric(string str)
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$");
        }
    }
```

my JsonResponse.ashx file

```
public class JsonResponse : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState 
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";    
        DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.QueryString["start"]);
        DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.QueryString["end"]);

        List<int> idList = new List<int>();
        List<ImproperCalendarEvent> tasksList = new List<ImproperCalendarEvent>();

        //Generate JSON serializable events
        foreach (CalendarEvent cevent in EventDAO.getEvents(start, end))
        {
            tasksList.Add(new ImproperCalendarEvent {
                id = cevent.id,
                title = cevent.name,
                start = String.Format("{0:s}", cevent.start),
                end = String.Format("{0:s}", cevent.end),
                
                description = cevent.description,
                allDay = cevent.allDay,
            });
            idList.Add(cevent.id);
        }

        context.Session["idList"] = idList;

        //Serialize events to string
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(tasksList);

        //Write JSON to response object
        context.Response.Write(sJSON);
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

the CalendarEvent.cs class which has all properties regarding events

```
public class CalendarEvent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    public bool allDay { get; set; }
}
```

my dataaccess class-EventDAO.cs that speaks to the database

```
public class EventDAO
{
    //change the connection string as per your database connection.
    //string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnString"];
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
    //this method retrieves all events within range start-end
    public static List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {   
        List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id,name, description, eventstart, eventend, isFullDay,IsHalfDay,IsQuatDay FROM Events where eventstart between @start AND @end or eventend between @start and @end", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = start;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = end;
        
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                events.Add(new CalendarEvent() {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                    name = Convert.ToString(reader["name"]),
                    description = Convert.ToString(reader["description"]),
                    start = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["eventstart"]),
                    end = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["eventend"]),
                    allDay = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["isFullDay"])
                });
            }
        }
        return events;
        //side note: if you want to show events only related to particular users,
        //if user id of that user is stored in session as Session["userid"]
        //the event table also contains an extra field named 'user_id' to mark the event for that particular user
        //then you can modify the SQL as:
        //SELECT event_id, description, title, event_start, event_end FROM event where user_id=@user_id AND event_start>=@start AND event_end<=@end
        //then add paramter as:cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", HttpContext.Current.Session["userid"]);
    }

    //this method updates the event title and description
    public static void updateEvent(int id, String title, String description)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Events SET name=@title, description=@description WHERE id=@event_id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = title;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= description;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;

        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    //this method updates the event start and end time ... allDay parameter added for FullCalendar 2.x
    public static void updateEventTime(int id,string title,string description, DateTime start, DateTime end, bool allDay)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Events SET name=@title,description=@description,eventstart=@event_start, eventend=@event_end, isFullDay=@all_day WHERE id=@event_id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = start;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = end;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@all_day", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = allDay;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    //this method deletes event with the id passed in.
    public static void deleteEvent(int id)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Events WHERE (id = @event_id)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;

        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    //this method adds events to the database
    public static int addEvent(CalendarEvent cevent)
    {
        //add event to the database and return the primary key of the added event row

        //insert
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Events(name, description, eventstart, eventend, isFullDay) VALUES(@title, @description, @event_start, @event_end, @all_day)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cevent.name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cevent.description;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cevent.start;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cevent.end;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@all_day", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = cevent.allDay;

        int key = 0;
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //get primary key of inserted row
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT max(id) FROM Events where name=@title AND description=@description AND eventstart=@event_start AND eventend=@event_end AND isFullDay=@all_day", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cevent.name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cevent.description;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cevent.start;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@event_end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cevent.end;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@all_day", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = cevent.allDay;

            key = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        return key;
    }
}
```

another class used in between javascript and asp.net

ImproperCalendarEvent.cs

```
public class ImproperCalendarEvent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public bool allDay { get; set; }
}
```

the javascript file code -calendarscript.js

```
var currentUpdateEvent;
var addStartDate;
var addEndDate;
var globalAllDay;

function updateEvent(event, element) {
    alert(event.description);

    if ($(this).data("qtip")) $(this).qtip("destroy");

    currentUpdateEvent = event;

    $('#updatedialog').dialog('open');
    $("#eventName").val(event.title);
    $("#eventDesc").val(event.description);
    $("#eventId").val(event.id);
    $("#eventStart").text("" + event.start.toLocaleString());

    if (event.end === null) {
        $("#eventEnd").text("");
    }
    else {
        $("#eventEnd").text("" + event.end.toLocaleString());
    }
    return false;
}

function updateSuccess(updateResult) {
    

    alert(updateResult);

}

function deleteSuccess(deleteResult) {
    alert(deleteResult);
}

function addSuccess(addResult) {
    // if addresult is -1, means event was not added
    //    alert("added key: " + addResult);

    if (addResult != -1) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
            {
                title: $("#addEventName").val(),
                start: addStartDate,
                end: addEndDate,
                id: addResult,
                description: $("#addEventDesc").val(),
                allDay: globalAllDay
            },
            true // make the event "stick"
        );


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
}

function UpdateTimeSuccess(updateResult) {
    alert(updateResult);
}

function selectDate(start, end, allDay) {

    $('#addDialog').dialog('open');
    $("#addEventStartDate").text("" + start.toLocaleString());
    $("#addEventEndDate").text("" + end.toLocaleString());

    addStartDate = start;
    addEndDate = end;
    globalAllDay = allDay;
    //alert(allDay);
}

function updateEventOnDropResize(event, allDay) {

    //alert("allday: " + allDay);
    var eventToUpdate = {
        id: event.id,
        start: event.start
    };

    if (event.end === null) {
        eventToUpdate.end = eventToUpdate.start;
    }
    else {
        eventToUpdate.end = event.end;
    }

    var endDate;
    if (!event.allDay) {
        endDate = new Date(eventToUpdate.end + 60 * 60000);
        endDate = endDate.toJSON();
    }
    else {
        endDate = eventToUpdate.end.toJSON();
    }

    eventToUpdate.start = eventToUpdate.start.toJSON();
    eventToUpdate.end = eventToUpdate.end.toJSON(); //endDate;
    eventToUpdate.allDay = event.allDay;

    PageMethods.UpdateEventTime(eventToUpdate, UpdateTimeSuccess);
}

function eventDropped(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
    if ($(this).data("qtip")) $(this).qtip("destroy");

    updateEventOnDropResize(event);
}

function eventResized(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {
    if ($(this).data("qtip")) $(this).qtip("destroy");

    updateEventOnDropResize(event);
}

function checkForSpecialChars(stringToCheck) {
    //var pattern = /[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/;
    //return pattern.test(stringToCheck); 
    return true;
}

function isAllDay(startDate, endDate) {
    var allDay;

    if (startDate.format("HH:mm:ss") == "00:00:00" && endDate.format("HH:mm:ss") == "00:00:00") {
        allDay = true;
        globalAllDay = true;
    }
    else {
        allDay = false;
        globalAllDay = false;
    }

    return allDay;
}

function qTipText(start, end, description) {
    var text;

    if (end !== null)
        text = "<strong>Start:</strong> " + start.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm T") + "<br/><strong>End:</strong> " + end.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm T") + "<br/><br/>" + description;
    else
        text = "<strong>Start:</strong> " + start.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm T") + "<br/><strong>End:</strong><br/><br/>" + description;

    return text;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // update Dialog
    $('#updatedialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 470,
        buttons: {
            "update": function () {
                alert(currentUpdateEvent.title);
                var eventToUpdate = {
                    id: currentUpdateEvent.id,
                    name: $("#eventName").val(),
                    description: $("#eventDesc").val()
                };
               
                PageMethods.UpdateEvent(eventToUpdate, updateSuccess);
                $(this).dialog("close");

                currentUpdateEvent.title = $("#eventName").val();
                currentUpdateEvent.description = $("#eventDesc").val();
                
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', currentUpdateEvent);

               



            },
            "delete": function () {

                if (confirm("do you really want to delete this event?")) {

                    PageMethods.deleteEvent($("#eventId").val(), deleteSuccess);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', $("#eventId").val());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //add dialog
    $('#addDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 470,
        buttons: {
            "Add": function () {
                //alert("sent:" + addStartDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "==" + addStartDate.toLocaleString());
                var eventToAdd = {
                    title: $("#addEventName").val(),
                    description: $("#addEventDesc").val(),
                    start: addStartDate.toJSON(),
                    end: addEndDate.toJSON(),

                    allDay: isAllDay(addStartDate, addEndDate)
                };

                if (checkForSpecialChars(eventToAdd.title) || checkForSpecialChars(eventToAdd.description)) {
                    alert("please enter characters: A to Z, a to z, 0 to 9, spaces");
                }
                else {
                    //alert("sending " + eventToAdd.title);

                    PageMethods.addEvent(eventToAdd, addSuccess);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var options = {
        weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "short",
        day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
    };

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today customBtn',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        customButtons: {
            customBtn: {
                text: 'Custom Button',
                click: function () {
                    alert('This custom button is hot! \nNow go have fun!');
                }
            }
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        eventClick: updateEvent,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: selectDate,
        editable: true,
        events: "JsonResponse.ashx",
        eventDrop: eventDropped,
        eventResize: eventResized,
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            //alert(event.title);
            element.qtip({
                content: {
                    text: qTipText(event.start, event.end, event.description),
                    title: '<strong>' + event.title + '</strong>'
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'bottom left',
                    at: 'top right'
                },
                style: { classes: 'qtip-shadow qtip-rounded' }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you've been on it for weeks then surely you have done some debugging and can describe the problem a little more clearly than just "doesn't reflect in the database". Narrow down the problem please and only show code which relates to your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance

Comment: yes i debugged it and there seems to be no error on the network tools/console or anywhere.. the event -- like edit and delete however reflects on the UI but not to the database, sorry for the showing all the code. all were connected somehow, so I thought its important to show the code needed.. thanks

Comment: What about server side debugging? Have used the visual studio debugger, and have you verified that the correct methods are fired and that cmd.executenonquery is being executed? Are there any exceptions from the c# code?

Comment: yes, i have tried that too.. so the debug points are only hit for the "public static List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)" --ie. the getevents method that fetches records from the database alone is hit.. no one other methods are being even called, so it makes it hard to even debug let alone get any error message!

Comment: Very strange. Have tou stepped through the JavaScript code then, to ensure the `PageMethods...` lines are actually being run when they need to? It's a while since I've worked with WebForms (thankfully!) but I believe those are supposed to trigger the C# methods via AJAX, is that right?

Comment: yes, it's supposed but I have no idea why the corresponding web methods are not fired. i don't know how to put a debug code on javascript code. is there any way for it to debug the javascript code like how we debug normal c# code in VS? Also, when I place the web methods in an ASMX file it gets fired!! thanks a lot for your time. You have been a ray of hope in my tunnel of darkness. Thanks :)